# ImmutableJS, deep nested node deletion

Tags: javascript, recursion, immutable.js

I have a structure as shown below stored in an immutable list constructed using **Immutable.fromJS** method

```
[{
  key:"1",
  children:[
    {key:"1.1"},
    {key:"1.2"},
    {key:"1.3",
      children:[
        {key:"1.3.1"}
      ]
    }]
}]
```

The requirement is to delete a given node by its *key* attribute. The Key attribute is unique within the structure. I have written the following code to achieve the functionality, however I am not sure if the solution is correct or can be accepted as ImmutableJS way of doing it. Requesting expert opinion from the ImmutableJS community.

```
const remove = (dom, key, value) => {
  if (!dom) return;

  // List Level
  if (Immutable.List.isList(dom)) {
    let index = dom.findIndex(function (item) {
      return item.get(key) === value;
    });

    if (index >= 0) return dom.delete(index);

    return dom.map((item) => remove(item, key, value));
  }

  // Children of the list
  let ch = dom.get(CHILDREN_ATTRIBUTE);

  if (ch) {
    let chIndex = ch.findIndex(function (item) {
      return item.get(key) === value;
    });

    if (chIndex >= 0) {
      return dom.set(CHILDREN_ATTRIBUTE, ch.delete(chIndex));
    }

    // We are here, let us try the children's children
    return dom.set(CHILDREN_ATTRIBUTE,
      dom.get(CHILDREN_ATTRIBUTE)
         .map((v) => remove(v, key, value)));
  }

  return dom;
};
```

JSBin for the above code given below
https://jsbin.com/bihowu/edit?js,console

Comment: Wouldn't this be a lot easier if you could change the structure to this -
`{
"1": {
 "1.1": {
  "1.1.1":{ "and so on..."}
 },
 "1.2":{"and so on..."}
}}`
Then you could write a generic method which recursively iterates until it finds the item with the matching key and deletes it. If your keys are actually patterned like "1", "1.1", "1.2" and so on, then you could optimize lookup by only going deep when the parent key matches the starting pattern of the child key.

Comment: The structure is for managing HTML DOM like structure, I thought the list of children inside a map will help maintain the order. I also do not want to be constrained by having to manage the keys. Keys will be arbitrary unique strings like an uuid string. Sorry this was not made very clear in my question.

Comment: Is there anything inherently bad or not optimal in my implementation, if so please can you clarify.

Comment: It's just that you are using array even though the children are guaranteed to have unique keys. Better suited as a map. The current structure could be optimized the way I suggested making operations easier.